# how to find the error in blazor wabassembly app(very difficult to find the error)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

difficulty to find the error in webassembly(client side) blazor

I am calling server side(blazor server app) webapi in client side((blazor webassembly app))

**first I create a blazor server app project and then use built in webapi framework for crud operation**

[image: API response]

when I calling the webapi in client side then very very difficulty to find the error

**then I create a blazor webassembly project and then add this below razor page inside pages folder**

DisplayEmployeeData.razor

```
@page "/DisplayEmployeeData"
@using CrudBlazorServerApp.Data
@using System.Net.Http
@inject HttpClient Http

<h3>DisplayEmployeeData</h3>

@if (empList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>empid</th>
                <th>username</th>
                <th>empaddress</th>
                <th>password</th>
                <th>country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var emp in empList)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@emp.empid</td>
                <td>@emp.username</td>
                <td>@emp.empaddress</td>
                <td>@emp.password</td>
                <td>@emp.country</td>

            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    Emp[] empList;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() =>
        empList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Emp[]>("api/emps/"); //**here I put the debugger but emplist give the null**
}
```

[image: Browser screenshot with error]

what type error?

my webapi path is wrong?

see my console log very very difficulty to find the error?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220659/discussion-on-question-by-rahul-patil-how-to-find-the-error-in-blazor-wabassembl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about `<` not being the valid start of a Json response, which indeed it isn't.

You are getting back an HTML page (with error information, probably).

From the text I gather that you created 2 separate projects. That means `"api/emps/"` cannot be a valid route. Your API and Client are probably running on localhost:xxxx and localhost:yyyy .

When you have fixed that routing you will probably run into a CORS problem, configure it on your server.

Be aware that a basic setup for this is provided when you create a Blazor Webassembly app and check the 'Hosted' box.

---

Try

```
empList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Emp[]>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps");
```

and in your server Startup.Configure()

```
app.UseCors(policy => 
    policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44399")  // client address 
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType));
```

Comment: yes exactly as you said and  Camilo Terevinto  said right but when I run server side project and response is json ```localhost:44333/api/emps```

Comment: Yes, but 44333 is not in the url in your client . And I assume it runs on a different port.

Comment: api response in client side is 200 ok why need to change route as you  said see my api response in client side https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKD06.png

Comment: please dont assume I give perfect url because I am not able to solve this problem last 3 days https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MgeG.png that is the reason I am coming here(Stack overflow) but not able to solve my problem

Comment: see My project hierarchy https://i.stack.imgur.com/hisaI.png

Comment: "api response in client side is 200" - yes, that is 200 for the HTML error page. Try with an invalid URL , like `"ipa/umps"`, I would then expect 200 as well.

Comment: like "ipa/umps", I would then expect 200 as well.  yes you are right

Comment: So work back from that. "api/emps/" is also invalid,. See my last edit.

Comment: again give same error(I change browser also) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg4Tz.png and see my project structure  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvPbR.png

Comment: I changed the suggestion again.

Comment: as you said few time ago  this error come now ```Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44333/api/emps. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).```

Comment: what should do I next?

Comment: Configure CORS in the API server (Startup). Look for a sample.

Comment: @HenkHolterman please see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRtT2.png

Comment: OK, you also need a services.AddCors(...). Here is a page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: thank you sir thanks for your support see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M9lc.png and see this cors image https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9wy0.png