# The provided ContentType is not supported; the supported types are 'application/json' in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am calling a blazor serverapp(webwebapi) in blazor webassemblyapp(client side) but I am facing content type error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: The provided ContentType is not supported; the supported types are 'application/json' and the structured syntax suffix 'application/+json'.
System.NotSupportedException: The provided ContentType is not supported; the supported types are 'application/json' and the structured syntax suffix 'application/+json'.
  at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.ValidateContent (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content) <0x32571f8 + 0x0009a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync[T] (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x3256ff0 + 0x00006> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsyncCore[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] taskResponse, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x321fd50 + 0x0011c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at CrudBlazorClientApp.Pages.Index.Login () [0x00106] in C:\Users\FrontTech\source\repos\CrudBlazorServerApp\CrudBlazorClientApp\Pages\Index.razor:31 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x3220cb0 + 0x000da> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x3156c98 + 0x000b6> in <filename unknown>:0
```

EmpsController.cs

```
namespace CrudBlazorServerApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmpsController : ControllerBase
    {
        //here I create a custom login webapi 
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        public Emp checkLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            Emp hasemp = _context.emps.Where(e => e.username == username & e.password == password).FirstOrDefault();
            return hasemp;
        }
```

see above webapi response

[image]

see watch window

[image]

see console log

[image]

Request Header

[image]

Response

failed to load response data

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using CrudBlazorServerApp.Data
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@*@inject CrudBlazorServerApp.Data.sqldbcontext _sqldbcontext*@
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
<div>
    UserName:<input id="txtusername" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your UserName" @bind="@username" /><br />
    Password:<input id="txtpassword" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Password" @bind="@password" /><br />
    <button @onclick="Login">Log In</button>
</div>

@code{
    string username = "";
    string password = "";
    Emp empList = new Emp();
    protected async Task Login()
    {
        @if (username == "" || username == null && password == "" || password == null)
        {
            var data = new
            {
                message = "Enter Username ",
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            empList = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/checkLogin?username=" + empList.username + "&password=" + empList.password);

            @if (username == empList.username || password == empList.password)
            {
                var data = new
                {
                    message = "Success",
                    data = new { empList.username, empList.password }
                };

                navigationManager.NavigateTo("/registration");

            }
            else
            {
                var data = new
                {
                    message = "Username and Password incorrect ",
                };
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("/index");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I am debugging this line generate an error:

```
empList = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/checkLogin?username=" + empList.username + "&password=" + empList.password);
```

and emplist is also null

help

Comment: Same error as you had [2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63644395/60761), same problem: your URL and route don't match.

Comment: @Henk Holterman issue solved

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a couple of issues here.

1. The method you are trying to reach is a POST

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public Emp checkLogin(string username, string password)
```

In your client side code, your are using

```cs
await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>(".....")
```

That method is making a GET request, not a POST request. It seems to me that the method you want is [PostAsJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-5.0)

2. The endpoint seems to be incorrect. In Postman, the URL you are invoking and is working (with a POST request) is `https://localhost:44333/api/emps?username=....`, in your C# code it is `https://localhost:44333/api/emps/checkLogin?username=....`
3. (This is what your code is complaining about) The error you are getting is because HTTP header `Content-Type` is not `application/json`. You might need to specify this header:

```cs
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

4. This is not causing server error, but you might want to consider not passing credentials as query strings even if your application runs on HTTPS. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499591/are-https-urls-encrypted) question has good answers related to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this line:

`empList = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/checkLogin?username=" + empList.username + "&password=" + empList.password);`

To

`empList = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps/checkLogin?username=" + username + "&password=" + password);`

Comment: I change this line as you said but give same error see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/35NGV.png  and  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz6mB.png